# Most efficient way to add dialog to qnamaker bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

QnA maker bots are easy to implement and offer great value. In some cases I need to add a dialog to a QnaMaker bot. I am struggling with the best approach to do this. The samples I tried all start with a non QnAmaker main dialog.

My goals is the start of a dialog (to get contact details) after a certain answer from the QnA Service (#contact). Some guidance is appreciated.

I created a dialog component to retrieve a user profile. I used the multi-prompt example as guidance. The dialog is indeed started after a certain result of a QnAMaker query.

```
// user requests to be contacted
            case '#Contact': {
                await this.dialog.run(turnContext, this.dialogState);
                break;
```

The first step of the dialog set is started. And after entering a response, the process fails. The answer is send to the QnA service again and not used as input (result) for the next step in the dialog component.

I expect the reason to be that all results are sent to the QnA service by the onTurn handler.

My questions:

- Can this even be done. Will I be able (without to much refactoring) to start a simple dialog from a QnA bot.
- Is there a way to check if there is an active Dialog. If so, I might be able to solve it by using that.

  I am thinking about something like this:

```
 this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            console.log('Any active Dialog we need to finish?');
            AciveDialog ? ResumeDialog : const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);
```

The documentation and samples were not very helpfull so any help is much appreciated.

My botcode until now. I did no link the dialog component because I expect that not to be part of the problem.

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

// Microsoft Bot Framework components
const { AttachmentLayoutTypes, ActivityTypes, ActivityHandler, CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const { QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');

// Making sure the time is mentioned correctly
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
require('moment/locale/nl');

// Helper funtions (forecast, welcome-message, cards, storage)
const helper = require('./helper');

// Introcard for welcome message
const IntroCard = require('./resources/IntroCard.json');

class QnAMakerBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(endpoint, qnaOptions, conversationState, userState, dialog) {
        super();
        this.qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(endpoint, qnaOptions);
        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty('DialogState');
    }

    async onTurn(turnContext) {
        // First check if a new user joined the webchat, if so, send a greeting message to the user.
        if (turnContext.activity.name === 'webchat/join') {
            await turnContext.sendActivity({ type: 'typing' });
            await turnContext.sendActivity({
                attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(IntroCard)]
            });
        };
        // if a user sent a message, show some response (1) and construct an answer (2).
        if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
            // (1)typing indicator with a short delay to improve user experience
            await turnContext.sendActivity({ type: 'typing' });
            // (2) Perform a call to the QnA Maker service to retrieve matching Question and Answer pairs.
            const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(turnContext);
            // for learning purposes store all questions with qnaMaker score.
            if (turnContext.activity.name !== 'webchat/join') {
                let score = (qnaResults[0] != null) ? qnaResults[0].score : 'No answer found';
                helper.storeQuestions(turnContext, score);
            };
            // If QnAMaker found an answer that might be correct, first check for responses that need additional work
            // If so, do the additional work, otherwise (default) send the QnA answer to the user
            if (qnaResults[0] && qnaResults[0].score > 0.5) {
                switch (qnaResults[0].answer) {
                // user requests a weatherforecast
                case '#Weather': {
                    var weatherForecast = await helper.getWeatherForecast(turnContext);
                    await turnContext.sendActivity({
                        attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(weatherForecast)]
                    });
                    break;
                }
                // user requests current date and/or time
                case '#DateTime': {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity(moment().tz('Europe/Amsterdam').format('[Today is ]LL[ and the time is  ] LT'));
                    break;
                }
                // user requests help or a startmenu
                case '#Help': {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity({
                        attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(IntroCard)]
                    });
                    break;
                }
                // user requests an overview of current bots
                case '#Bots': {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity({
                        attachments: helper.createBotsGallery(turnContext),
                        attachmentLayout: AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel
                    });
                    break;
                }
                // user requests to be contacted. This is were the magic should happen ;-)
                case '#Contact': {
                    await this.dialog.run(turnContext, this.dialogState);
                    break;
                }
                // if no 'special' requests, send the answer found in QnaMaker
                default: {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity(qnaResults[0].answer);
                    break;
                }
                }
            // QnAmaker did not find an answer with a high probability
            } else {
                await turnContext.sendActivity('Some response');
            }
        }
    }

    async onMessage(turnContext, next) {
        // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
        await this.dialog.run(turnContext, this.dialogState);

        await next();
    };

    async onDialog(turnContext, next) {
        // Save any state changes. The load happened during the execution of the Dialog.
        await this.conversationState.saveChanges(turnContext, false);
        await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext, false);
        await next();
    };
}

module.exports.QnAMakerBot = QnAMakerBot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this thru the use of [component dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-compositcontrol?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript).

In the following example, I have one component dialog which 'listens' to user input. In this case, for the user to enter something related to getting a user name. If there is a match, it makes a QnA call to retrieve the answer/response. Once the answer has been retrieved and displayed, the bot then begins an intermediary(child) dialog before returning back to the main dialog.

First, create the component dialog you want to route to following any successful QnA responses. I have named this file 'getUserNameDialog.js'.

```js
const {
  TextPrompt,
  ComponentDialog,
  WaterfallDialog
} = require('botbuilder-dialogs');

const GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG = 'GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG';
const TEXT_PROMPT = 'TEXT_PROMPT';
const WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'WATERFALL_DIALOG';

class GetUserNameDialog extends ComponentDialog {
  constructor() {
    super(GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG);

    this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));
    this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
      this.getNameStep.bind(this),
      this.displayNameStep.bind(this)
    ]));
    this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
  }

  async getNameStep(stepContext) {
    return await stepContext.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, "Let's makeup a user name for fun. Enter something.");

    // return stepContext.next();
  }
  async displayNameStep(stepContext) {
    const stepResults = stepContext.result;
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`${ stepResults } is a fine name!`);

    return stepContext.endDialog();
  }
}
module.exports.GetUserNameDialog = GetUserNameDialog;
module.exports.GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG = GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG;
```

Next, create the QnA dialog (I have named it qnaResponseDialog.js). My QnA credentials are stored in a .env file where they are retrieved from. Note that I require the 'getUserNameDialog' file I created just above.

When there is a match/response from QnA (I'm looking for some reference to 'user name'), then I call beginDialog() which starts the child dialog. I'm doing this by mapping the questions returned within the QnA response and matching on the user input. If 'user' and/or 'name' is in any of the questions, then I return true. If true, then I return the QnA response and begin the child dialog.

This matching process is pretty unsophisticated and is more for demonstration, but if it works for you then great. However, I would recommend you look at using [LUIS](http://luis.ai) to match on user intents. It will make this process that much cleaner and simpler to maintain.

```js
const { ComponentDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');
const { GetUserNameDialog, GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG } = require('./getUserNameDialog');

class QnAResponseDialog extends ComponentDialog {
  constructor() {
    super(GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG);
    this.addDialog(new GetUserNameDialog());

    try {
      this.qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
        knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
        endpointKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
        host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(`QnAMaker Exception: ${ err } Check your QnAMaker configuration in .env`);
    }
  }

  async onBeginDialog(innerDc, options) {
    const result = await this.interrupt(innerDc);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
    return await super.onBeginDialog(innerDc, options);
  }

  async onContinueDialog(innerDc) {
    const result = await this.interrupt(innerDc);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
    return await super.onContinueDialog(innerDc);
  }

  async interrupt(innerDc) {
    if (innerDc.context.activity.type === 'message') {
      const text = innerDc.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();

      const stepResults = innerDc.context;

      let qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(stepResults);
      console.log(qnaResults[0]);
      stepResults.qna = qnaResults[0];

      if (qnaResults[0]) {
        let mappedResult = null;
        const includesText = qnaResults[0].questions.map((question) => {
          if (text.includes('user') || text.includes('name')) {
            mappedResult = true;
          } else {
            mappedResult = false;
          }
          console.log('RESULTS: ', mappedResult);
        });

        console.log('MAPPED: ', mappedResult);

        switch (mappedResult) {
        case true:
          let answer = stepResults.qna.answer;
          await innerDc.context.sendActivity(answer);
          return await innerDc.beginDialog(GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports.QnAResponseDialog = QnAResponseDialog;
```

Lastly, in your main or top level dialog, include the following:

```js
const { QnAResponseDialog } = require('./qnaResponseDialog');

class MainDialg extends QnAResponseDialog {
  [...]
}
```

At this point, if all is configured correctly, when a user types a phrase QnA recognizes and accepts it should interrupt the current dialog, display the QnA response, begin the child component dialog and, once completed, return back to the parent dialog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will look into component dialogs. I actually would like to continue to leverage QnaMaker for chatbots. I am able to cover most use cases until know (especially in combination with follow up prompts) but need to be able to add dialogs for 'special' purposed. Component dialogs in its name sounds like what I need. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Hi, I created the component dialog with some dialogsteps to create a userprofile. The example above is very helpfull but not completely what I am looking for. I want to start the component dialog from my QnAbot (if (qnaResults[0] = '#contact). That is the easy part. But how do I make sure the next dialog step is executed as soon as the user sends a reply? I currently only have onTurn in my bot.js. Do I need to check state to see if a dialog is active and start that dialog again?

Comment: Disregard my latent comment. Read the updated documentation on dialogs and will refactor my code

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Tnx. small question . I refactored everything based on the complex dialog scenario in the samples library ending up with something very similar to your code ;-) One thing is bugging me. I use onMemberAdded to show a welcome message with some opions/questions (via adaptive card). The next dialog is however only started 'after' the user sends a message. Is there a way to start a new dialog without any user interaction after onMembersAdded is ended after 
 next().

Comment: This is not hard to do. Can you post this as a new question? Happy to provide an answer there.

Comment: Hi Steven, Wrt your code. In the constructor of 'qnaResponseDialog.js', you use super(GET_USER_NAME_DIALOG) and add a dialog to the set via 
    this.addDialog(new GetUserNameDialog());
Why this approach? This way I will not be able to start multiple dialogs from within one dialog.

Comment: it is just a practice I picked up, primarily from the official samples. It's not required, by any means. Alter the code to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is going to be to use the botbuilder-dialogs library https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs

Using the botbuilder prepackaged libraries/dialog classes will be easier then attempting a to do it from scratch. Things like simple prompts are readily available.

The Botbuilder-Samples repository have functionality specific examples so you wont be overwhelmed by looking through a large scale bot code or reading Microsoft's confusing documentation trying to find what you need.

Seems the your simply looking to prompt for input so this will be pergect for what you need 
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/44.prompt-for-user-input